# How to replace space with %20 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I do

```
str= "  John   Smith Beer "
str.tr(" ", "%20")
"%%John%%%Smith%Beer%"
```

It doesn't replace it with "%20".
How to fix it?

Comment: Assuming this is to be used for a URL ... you could just leave the space in. Browsers will do this conversion for you before submitting the request. Otherwise - the solution from MilesStanfield is most appropriate.

Comment: Rails usually handles this conversion. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes on browser its work...Issue which I face is that this is ans API and on mobile video this doesn't work because of spaces...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
require 'uri'
URI.encode("green books")
# => "green%20books"
```

Comment: In ruby 3, use  `require 'erb'; ERB::Util.url_encode('green book')`